# How can I run HTML Selenese Tests using Selenium 2.0 and Maven?

Tags: maven, selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-webdriver

I have a series of HTML tests that I am able to run using the selenese goal, selenium-maven-plugin (version 1.1). I was able to run this for IE. However, this doesn't work with Firefox 4. I keep getting a blank firefox window opening up and the server will just hang there. I believe that I've narrowed the problem down to the fact that the Selenium-maven-plugin uses the old Selenium 1.0 Core, which doesn't function properly with Firefox 4.

I was wondering if there was some way, using Maven and Selenium 2.0, to run these HTML tests. The following is a snippet of my POM file.

```
     ...    
     <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <browser>*iexploreproxy</browser>
                <suite>src/test/selenium/html/suite.html</suite>
                <startURL>http://localhost:5555/</startURL>
                <port>5555</port>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>Run-Selenese-Scripts</id>
                    <phase>integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>selenese</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <port>5555</port>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    ...
```

If there is any other way to run the HTML suites (besides the Selenium IDE) that I may have missed, please share.

Thanks,

Juan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this exact problem yesterday on OSX. Trying to use firefox 4 - a blank firefox window opens up and selenium-server doesn't detect it.  The only version which fixes this problem (on OSX anyway) is 2.0b3.

I've got a fork of current trunk of upgraded to 2.0b3 on github: https://github.com/thelmstedt/selenium-maven-plugin. YMMV

There is actually a way to override the selenium version in selenium-maven-plugin plugin declaration: see [this jira issue](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MSELENIUM-69) for someone troubleshooting it.

**But** the selenium folks have changed their maven packaging recently, and I was unable to use this to override to the latest 2.0b3 dependency.  Compare the uploaded [version 2.0b1](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium/2.0b1/) with [2.0b3](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium/2.0b3/). The correct way to declare a dependency on selenium is now with `<type>pom</type>`.  I will be happy if it turns out I'm wrong on this.

Comment: Hi Tim, I tried overriding the selenium server as indicated in the JIRA you provided and this worked out great. I managed to get past the blank screen and into the Selenium Test Runner. However, the test runner doesn't automatically run my suite. I will look further into this. I will also look into using the forked plugin. Thank you very much for your suggestion.

Comment: Hi Tim, you are correct about the 2.0b3 artifact requiring a POM type to override the existing Selenium used by the maven plugin. I believe that it still works when overriding using the POM because the JARs are included within the class realm for the plugin. Please see the listing below.

Comment: [DEBUG]   Included: org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-server:jar:2.0b3